# Embed Content within Content

Tags: nodes

Is it possible to embed Drupal content within a different type of Drupal content?  I ask this question in the context of having Drupal maintain hundreds of product listings, each with a price.  Occasionally, we need to update those prices.   I am exploring ways of updating those prices within having to touch the base content.  It would be nice to create new prices for the new year, and at the appointed time, switch to those prices, rather than having to go through a tedious and time consuming process of updating them on, e.g. Jan 1.

Comment: Hi Jerry, Are you using Ubercart , Commerce or you want this in core Drupal ? You could try Entity Reference http://drupal.org/project/entityreference , create a new content type Price with start and end dates and add node reference field to your product content type.