# Image gallery as a field, not a content type?

Tags: entities, media

Tutorials I've found seem to only cover [creating Image Gallery content types](https://drupal.org/node/2152441). Any suggestions on how to make an image gallery as a field, rather than as a content type?

Ideally, I'd like to have something similar to the [Photoswipe](http://photoswipe.com/) responsive galleries, but with captions, and appearing inside another content type, be it an article, basic page or in this case a new content type.

Perhaps there's simply something I'm missing about [embedding one content type within another](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27213/embed-content-within-content)?

Comment: Have tried [Field collection](https://drupal.org/project/field_collection)?

Answer (score 1):

Make a View for your gallery and put that view in a block. Then activate that block for the desired content type; putting that block in the region you want it to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Create a content type with image field. Create a view for that
  content type.
- create a tpl for the view
- Within the tpl you can write your code for  Photoswipe responsive galleries.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this. First create a content type, for example an `article` then create another content type called `gallery` and insert your images in there, its display must be [slideshow](https://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow). download and install [entity](https://drupal.org/project/entity) module and create a reference from `gallery` to `article`. in this way you can determine which image belongs to which `article`. download and install [eva](https://drupal.org/project/eva) module. go to this [link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/72355/views-with-entity-reference), it is a very good tutorial of `eva` module (you also need to set a contexual filter which in your case is going to be your article), then as I have asked in this [address](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/112303/why-eva-display-of-views-is-added-to-the-manage-display-of-content-type) a filed which is your slideshow will be attached to the manage display of `article` content type. now it is field of `article` nodes and can be reordered.

**`"Eva" is short for "Entity Views Attachment;" it provides a Views display plugin that allows the output of a View to be attached to the content of any Drupal entity.`**

**`The placement of the view in the entity's content can be reordered on the "Field Display" administration page for that entity, like other fields added using the Field UI module.`**